# Prove $o(g) | |G|$ using Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

I'm confused of the following steps:

- How did the lecturer form the subgroup $H$?
- How do we know that $H$ is cyclic?

if anyone could please explain, thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "How did the lecturer form the subgroup $H$?". As a set it simply exists and it happens to be a subgroup of $G$. For the second question, check the definition of cyclic group.

Comment: definition definition

Comment: @GitGud I still don't get how the subgroup simply exists ? As for the definition of a cyclic group we said if $\exists g \in G$ s.t. $<g > = G$ then $G$ is cyclic. HOw do we know there is such a $g$?

Comment: @Warz First question first. Can you accept that $H$ exists as a set?

Comment: @gitgud Yes I can

Comment: @ucf I have printed out my definition of a cyclic group

Comment: @Warz Can you prove that $H$ is a group?

Comment: @GitGud , no that's why I don't see how he has formed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments it was clarified that the OP doesn't understand why $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Clearly $H\subseteq G$. Let's prove that $H$ is a group. To do this it suffices to prove that

1. $\forall h_1, h_2\in H(h_1h_2\in H)$,
2. that the operation is associative,
3. that there exists an element $e\in H$ such that $\forall h\in H(eh=he=h)$,
4. and that $\forall h\in H\exists \overline h\in H(h\overline h=\overline hh=e)$.

For the first one take $h_1,h_2\in H$. There exist $i,j\in \mathbb Z$ such that $h_1=g^î$ and $h_2=g^j$, thus $h_1h_2=g^ig^j=g^{i+j}$ and $g^{i+j}\in H$ because $i+j\in \mathbb Z$.
The second one is an immediate consequence of the fact that the operation is associative in $G$.
To prove the third one, first note that the identity element in $G$, let's call it $1_G$, is equal to $g^0$. So let $e=1_G$ and it follows that $\forall h\in H(eh=he=h)$.
For the last one, take $h\in H$. There exists $i\in \mathbb Z$ such that $h=g^i$. Now let $\overline h =g^{-i}$. You can check that $\overline h$ has the desired properties.

By definition, $H$ is cyclic if, and only if, $H=\langle h\rangle$, for some $h\in H$. Also by definition, $\langle h\rangle=\{h^k\colon k\in \mathbb Z\}$. Can you find an $h$ that suits the bill?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of why it's a group. I still can't see why it is cyclic. I don't see any $h$ which generates $H$, because I don't really know what $H$ is. I mean, if we took a group $\mathbb{Z}^+_6$ I can find you a $h \in \mathbb{Z}^6$ which generates the group, but $H$ here is just any group, how can I find $h$?

Comment: @Warz But you do know what $H$ to a certain extent (it depends on $\color{red}g$).

Comment: then wouldn't $h=g$ generate the group? That's all I can really think of

Comment: @Warz Check it yourself. You know that $H=\{g^i\colon i\in \mathbb Z\}$. Now try to prove that $\langle g\rangle =H$.

Comment: This is back to the problem from my first comment, how can I prove a certain element generates a whole group when I don't know what the group is? Also, isn't what you stated the same statement? Definition of $<g> = \{ g^i | i \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Comment: Yes, it is the same statement, that's my point. The equality is trivial:$H=\{g^i\colon i\in \mathbb Z\}=\langle g\rangle$. Do you get it?

Comment: Yes I do, thank you very much for your patience.

Comment: @Warz You're welcome.